# Speech recognition using esp8266

Tags: esp8266

I'm working on a project where I have to send voice through mic to a Speech recognition API using esp8266 where the voice is get processed. Is there any possible way I could do this with esp8266?

I found a similar [project](https://github.com/happychriss/esp8266_speech_recognition) but it is not written for arduino ide and some of the things in the [code](https://github.com/happychriss/esp8266_speech_recognition/blob/master/src/main_esp8266_speech.cpp) are hard to understand like buffer part. please help me to understand the code.

Comment: that project appears to be written for the Arduino IDE, because it has setup() and loop() blocks

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the project you referenced working in the Arduino IDE.  It uses standard cpp files instead of ino files, but the project *does* use the Arduino framework (`#include <Arduino.h>`).  I believe there are tutorials online on how to import standard C++ code into the Arduino IDE.  As long as there aren't any namespace conflicts with global variables between modules, it'll probably work.

The buffer is just a standard way of passing data (usually a byte array) between functions using a variable of a known fixed sized so that memory can be allocated appropriately.  In trying to understand the code, just think of it as you would any other variable.